# ErrorException in Macroable.php line 74: Method links does not exist

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5.3

First i implement pagination in laravel and now i want to remove when i remove `//$user = customer::paginate(2);`  and links `<!-- {{ $user->links() }} -->` 
now its not running and displaying an error

**ErrorException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method links does not exist. (View: C:\wamp64\www\laravel_crud\resources\views\viewall.blade.php)**

**viewall.blade.php**

```
    <body>

    <a href="insert">Insert Customer</a>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

<table>

<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Grnder</th>
<th>Favorite</th>
<th>Image</th>
<th>Show By Id</th>
<th>Update</th>
<th>Delete</th>

</tr>
<tbody>


@foreach($user as $users)
<tr>
    <td>{{$users->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$users->email}}</td>
    <td>{{$users->country}}</td>
    <td>{{$users->gender}}</td>
    <td>{{$users->favorite}}</td>
    <td><img src="{{URL::to('/image/' . $users->image)}}" alt="" width=
        "50px" height="50px"></td>

    <td><a href="customer/{{$users->id}}">View By Id</td>
    <td><a href="edit/{{$users->id}}">Update</td>
    <td><a href="delete/{{$users->id}}">Delete</td>

    </tr>

    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
```

**Controller**

```
public function showall(){
    $user = customer::all();

//$user = customer::paginate(2);


return view("viewall" , compact ('user'));

    }
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get("showall" , "testing@showall");
```

Please Help to fix it Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Blade comments `{{-- {{ $user->links() }} --}}`
With HTML comments `<!-- {{ this still running }} -->`

Comment: Fixed my problem